# Converting CSS Linear Gradient to HTML5's Canvas Linear gradient

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have a HTML5 canvas on which I have drawn a full fledged table. I have the option to give a background color to the table headers. Although normal background color works, I am unable to apply the linear gradient correctly. I get the linear gradient in this format

`background: linear-gradient(55deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0%, rgb(128, 0, 128) 50%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 100%);`

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034238/css-convert-gradient-to-the-canvas-version/#answer-45037652) available solution, but it doesn't seem to work in  all cases. I need to know how to exactly calculate the end points of the gradient line since the canvas linearGradient() expects it that way.

https://jsfiddle.net/LpLr0hxw/2/

Comment: You can find a correct version in [html2canvas sources](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/0b9f34a5bf1cafad260506f5b353aeb8d610612c/src/Gradient.js#L273) https://jsfiddle.net/LpLr0hxw/5

Comment: This seems to work fine. Thank you so much :)